# this.app.database is not a function when using firebase-server for unit testing

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use firebase-server (https://github.com/urish/firebase-server) for unit testing an express app that uses firebase. However, I'm starting out by just running the firebase-server on my own machine.

I've installed the library locally: `npm install --save-dev firebase-server`

Then using the documentation for firebase-server, it says

> If installed locally, use the following path to start the server: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase-server
>
> The following command will start a firebase server on port 5555:
>
> `firebase-server -p 5555`

From the root of my project, I run `./node_modules/.bin/firebase-server -p 5555`

The result is:

```
/Users/user/Work/myproject/node_modules/firebase-server/dist/index.js:78
        this.app.database().goOffline();
                 ^

TypeError: this.app.database is not a function
    at new FirebaseServer (/Users/user/Work/myproject/node_modules/firebase-server/dist/index.js:78:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Work/myproject/node_modules/firebase-server/bin/firebase-server.js:85:17)
    at Object.cli.main (/Users/user/Work/myproject/node_modules/cli/cli.js:957:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Work/myproject/node_modules/firebase-server/bin/firebase-server.js:30:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
```

Do I need to do some other configuration to get firebase-server to work via the cli?

Extra info:
I was able to get the server running if I install firebase-server globally, but still can't run it from my repo directory in `node_modules`

package.json

```
{
"name": "endpoints",
"description": "my description",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"license": "Apache-2.0",
"author": "JL",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples.git"
},
"engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "repo-tools test run --cmd ava -- -T 20s --verbose test/*.test.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^4.2.0",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "firebase-admin": "~4.2.1",
    "safe-buffer": "5.1.2",
    "firebase": "5.8.3",
    "@firebase/app": "0.3.8",
    "@firebase/auth": "0.9.2",
    "@firebase/database": "0.3.12",
    "request-promise": "4.2.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/nodejs-repo-tools": "^3.0.0",
    "ava": "0.25.0",
    "firebase-server": "^1.0.1",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "proxyquire": "2.1.0",
    "sinon": "7.2.2",
    "supertest": "3.3.0"
},
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-push": "npm test"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your package.json.
The problem is the dependency

        *"@firebase/app": "0.3.8",*

If you delete it from the package.json, then clean node_modules and package-lock files, re-install again your depencendies and you should see work the firebase server.

The npmjs page says to use it to create a client instance to connect to the server separately: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-server  
In addition in the @firebase/app page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/app) you can read:

> This package is not intended for direct usage, and should only be used via the officially supported firebase package.